# A Class Incompatible error when using maven-jira-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jira, jira-plugin

Recently I met a very queer error. When I use maven-jira-plugin to bundle my plugin project, I met a error like below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.3.2:test-jar (default-test-jar) on project step-bugzilla-plugin: Execution default-test-jar of goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.3.2:test-jar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.3.2:test-jar: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.util.TestClassVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

My maven-jira-plugin configuration is as below:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>6.3.2</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   <configuration>
      <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
      <productVersion>7.3.6</productVersion>
      <productDataVersion>7.3.6</productDataVersion>
      <shutdownTimeout>60000</shutdownTimeout>
      <offline>true</offline>
      <testBundleExcludes>
         <testBundleExclude>
            <groupId>atlassian</groupId>
         </testBundleExclude>
         <testBundleExclude>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
         </testBundleExclude>
      </testBundleExcludes>
   </configuration>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.rest</groupId>
         <artifactId>atlassian-rest-doclet</artifactId>
         <version>2.9.5</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug of this plugin. Does anyone have similar problem? 
BTW, does anyone know how to skip the test-jar of this plugin?

**Updated**: Seems it is caused by the miss-configuration of the dependencies settings in the plugin setting of that atlassian-rest-doclet plugin. When updated to recently 5.0.1 version, problem solved.

Comment: Why are you using a supplemental plugin dependency why no using the plugin as plain ?

Comment: It has some conflict with other dependencies settings. And seems this is the problem, I've updated it to recently 5.0.1 rest-doclet and it works.